# Copy struct containing char* from kernel to user

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have a struct that looks like this:

```c
struct ProcStruct {
    pid_t procID;
    char *name;
};
```

On the kernel side, I've defined a system call that has this header

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(dfsproc, pid_t, pid, int32_t *, pidc, struct ProcStruct *, ps)
```

I'm trying to copy `kps` which has the same type as `ps` (which is `struct ProcStruct*` as mentioned in the syscall header) to the user accessible memory using:

```c
copy_to_user(ps, kps, sizeof(struct ProcStruct) * 256);
```

The problem is that this is actually a shallow copy, so `char *name` isn't copied.

---

What should I do in order to copy the `char*` into the user accessible memory?

Comment: You must allocate memory for each `char *name;` member and copy that data individually for each element. If it is a string you can use `strdup()` but the question isn't clear.

Comment: On windows at least the answer would be to redo the struct so that it directly contains the buffer, and also probably a length field.

Comment: No, you don't do this usually like that. Pointers in IOCTLs or syscalls are very nasty things.